# In HP and the Cursed Child, how did Malfoy not know about the Augurey?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

**If the Augurey was born in Malfoy Manor to his aunt, how did Draco Malfoy not know about her?**

He would've revealed her and cleared his son if he had known.

Comment: Maybe he was obliviated? Maybe he even asked for it? I know i would in his place. ..

Comment: Malfoy was at Hogwarts at the time she was born

Comment: @NKCampbell He was definitely around when she was pregnant (as per book 7) and would have known even if he was at Hogwarts when she was in labor.

Comment: how would he have known she was in labor? That's a huge assumption. Also - while we can assume the er....normal methods applied - given Voldemort's penchant for the dark and bizarre, there may very well be dark magic involved that is beyond what is normal. Purely speculation that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to go with the solutions in this question:

[When was Delphini born?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137235/when-was-delphini-born?rq=1)

Basically, that Bellatrix used concealment spells and had the baby a few months before the battle of Hogwarts, when Draco wasn't around.